# "My love for you" vs. "My love to you"

Tags: prepositions

What’s the difference between “my love for you” and “my love to you”? 
When is correct to use each one?

Answer (score 2):

"My love for you" can be used when you want to describe your love *for* someone: "My love for you is stronger than ..."

"My love to you" would be used when you wish to send your love *to* someone, perhaps in a time of grief: "I'm so sorry to hear about ___, I am sending all my love to you."

Comment: I would argue that the differences @Andrew Truett describes are significant despite the disclaimer that they are not.

Comment: In particular, "my love to you" is not a constituent the way "my love for you" is. "for you" modifies "my love", but "to you" modifies "sending".

Comment: @KnotWright I’m not sure why I claimed they were similar, and then gave two uses which were quite different. I have edited my response.

Comment: My love to you has to be in a context, as this answer shows clearly.